# GWT Unknown argument: -nosuperDevMode

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I have a problem with my GWT project, as it's compiled fine and generated war file successfully also it's working fine. But I tried to run it as GWT web application on my eclipse, it's return this message without creating the URL

```
Unknown argument: -nosuperDevMode
Google Web Toolkit 2.3.0
DevMode [-noserver] [-port port-number | "auto"] [-whitelist whitelist-             string] [-blacklist blacklist-string] [-logdir directory] [-logLevel level] [-  gen dir] [-bindAddress host-name-or-address] [-codeServerPort port-number |  "auto"] [-server servletContainerLauncher[:args]] [-startupUrl url] [-war dir]   [-deploy dir] [-extra dir] [-workDir dir] module[s] 

where 
      -noserver        Prevents the embedded web server from running
  -port            Specifies the TCP port for the embedded web server (defaults to 8888)
   -whitelist       Allows the user to browse URLs that match the specified    regexes (comma or space separated)
  -blacklist       Prevents the user browsing URLs that match the specified    regexes (comma or space separated)
   -logdir          Logs to a file in the given directory, as well as    graphically
  -logLevel        The level of logging detail: ERROR, WARN, INFO, TRACE,   DEBUG,    SPAM, or ALL
 -gen             Debugging: causes normally-transient generated types to be   saved in the specified directory
 -bindAddress     Specifies the bind address for the code server and web server (defaults to 127.0.0.1)
  -codeServerPort  Specifies the TCP port for the code server (defaults to 9997)
  -server          Specify a different embedded web server to run (must   implement ServletContainerLauncher)
  -startupUrl      Automatically launches the specified URL
  -war             The directory into which deployable output files will be written (defaults to 'war')
  -deploy          The directory into which deployable but not servable output   files will be written (defaults to 'WEB-INF/deploy' under the -war   directory/jar, and may be the same as the -extra directory/jar)
  -extra           The directory into which extra files, not intended for    deployment, will be written
   -workDir         The compiler's working directory for internal use (must be     writeable; defaults to a system temp dir)
    and 
     module[s]        Specifies the name(s) of the module(s) to host
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-nosuperDevMode` flag is only appropriate for GWT 2.6 or 2.7 and beyond - you should remove it from the argument list in the eclipse Run Configuration.

I'm not sure how it could have gotten there, unless you started with a newer version of GWT and then moved back to 2.3.0 (which is nearly [*five years old*](http://www.gwtproject.org/release-notes.html#Release_Notes_2_3_0)...).

Alternatively, move to a version of GWT released in the last few years (and able to support IE10, IE11, and the last [30 versions of Chrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome_release_history) and [35 versions of Firefox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox_release_history).

Comment: This is a bug in the GWT Eclipse plugin. You'll have to get the fork to use an older version. I fixed it in the fork.